# change the data directory gitlab to store repos elsewhere

Tags: git, gitlab

my basic disk is full for my gitlab installation, is it possible to move the repositories and their data to some other folder and make sure that the upcoming push's data is sent to those directories?

I tried stopping the gitlab and copying over the entire folder, but to no avail.
PS - I am not an IT guy, I am just pitching in to see how could we get out of this issue; so please be verbose when answering.

Answer (score 141):

Just updating in case people still refer to this. From the GitLab [documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/configuration.md#storing-git-data-in-an-alternative-directory):

> By default, omnibus-gitlab stores the Git repository data under
>   `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data`. The repositories are stored in a subfolder
>   `repositories`. You can change the location of the `git-data` parent
>   directory by adding the following line to `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`.
>
> ```
> git_data_dirs({"default" => "/mnt/nas/git-data"})
> ```
>
> Starting from GitLab 8.10 you can also add more than one git data
>   directory by adding the following lines to `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`
>   instead.
>
> ```
> git_data_dirs({
>   "default" => "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data",
>   "alternative" => "/mnt/nas/git-data"
> })
> ```
>
> Note that the target directories and any of its subpaths must not be a
>   symlink.
>
> Run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` for the changes to take effect.
>
> If you already have existing Git repositories in
>   `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data` you can move them to the new location as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> # Prevent users from writing to the repositories while you move them.
> sudo gitlab-ctl stop
>
> # Note there is _no_ slash behind 'repositories', but there _is_ a
> # slash behind 'git-data'.
> sudo rsync -av /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories /mnt/nas/git-data/
>
> # Fix permissions if necessary
> sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
>
> # Double-check directory layout in /mnt/nas/git-data. Expected output:
> # gitlab-satellites  repositories
> sudo ls /mnt/nas/git-data/
>
> # Done! Start GitLab and verify that you can browse through the repositories in
> # the web interface.
> sudo gitlab-ctl start
> ```

Comment: see also https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/629def0a7a26e7c2326566f0758d4a27857b52a3/README.md#storing-git-data-in-an-alternative-directory

Comment: Won't one need to start Postgres for gitlab-ctl reconfigure to work?

Comment: @Stéphane current link: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/configuration.md#storing-git-data-in-an-alternative-directory

Comment: The `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` command is VERY important, as not doing so will produces some 502 errors when navigating in GitLab or even worst.

Comment: What about single repo transfer?

Comment: @jeremiah I did shut down Gitlab before moving data (I stopped it by "systemctl status gitlab-runsvdir"), updated the path in gitlab.rb, started gitlab-runsvdir again, and found the symptoms mentioned by SiZiOUS. After that, while Gitlab was running, I issued gitlab-ctl reconfigure , and a gitlab-ctl restart. Problem solved

Answer (score 15):

Much easier solution **for new installs with the version > 7.14.1**:

Open the gitlab.rb configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

Search for `git_data_dir`, uncomment the line and set your directory here, e.g.

```
git_data_dir "/storage/data/gitlab/git-data"
```

Save the file and reconfigure Gitlab:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Answer (score 6):

I just moved my gitlab repositories folder from one directory to another, might be useful for someone (do this quickly at a quiet time or stop gitlab beforehand!)

Assuming you have a standard install the steps are

- Create a new folder for repos as root and change the owner to the git user
- Copy (with archive, recursive options) the old repo folder contents to its new home `cp -ar SOURCE DESTINATION`
- Edit the gitlab config file *and* the gitlab-shell config files with the new repo path
- Restart gitlab `sudo /etc/init.d/gitlab restart`

Comment: I forgot to edit the gitlab-shell config.yml and my pushes were being denied by the hook, this helped me realize the problem, thx!

Comment: Not working for wiki. UPD: for repository too. Am I doing something wrong? after cp -ar SOURCE* DESTINATION/ I delete in SOURCE forlder .git and .wiki.git

Comment: As pointed out in several responses around here, the sweet secret you're missing is gitlab-ctl reconfigure

Answer (score 6):

you need append this small config bellow:

```
git_data_dirs({
    "default" => {
        "path" => "/srv/gitlab/git-data"
    }
})
```

And

```
rsync -av /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/* /srv/gitlab/git-data/.
chown -R git:git /srv/gitlab/git-data/
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Done.

Answer (score 4):

If you're getting the `cannot find repo` error in GitLab after running the above steps.  Run this command.

```
gitlab-rake cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production
```

This should fix the issue if your pathing is correct.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I needed to move a repository from the `default` storage to `storage1`
If you load the project's general setting, it show the project number, for example `37`:

```
sudo gitlab-rails console
irb(main):012:0> p37 = Project.find(37)
irb(main):009:0> p37.repository_storage
=> "default"
irb(main):010:0> p37.repository_storage = 'storage1'
irb(main):011:0> p37.save
=> true
irb(main):012:0>  # <ctrl>+d to send EOF and exit
```

clearing the cache is probably a good idea too

[`gitlab-rake cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40458120/1695680)

Comment: Absolute lifesaver.  I just moved a few repos over to a new drive and then had a moment of pure terror when I saw that 'this is a blank/empty repo' message.   Found this and it fixed everything.  thank you so much

Comment: I know we should not write thanks comments, but same for me, THANKS @ThorSummoner