# Installing Gitlab with data in a different directory

Tags: gitlab

I would like to install Gitlab (omnibus, from a deb ), where the executables and /etc files go in their standard location, but the rest go in a tree based at /srv/gitlab.

It's not clear to me how to accomplish this modifying the configuration files,since there seem to be so many directories there. Can someone help?

**Edit**
There is this question:
[Data Dir relocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902417/change-the-data-directory-gitlab-to-store-repos-elsewhere) but it only answers part of the question git_data_dir changes the location of git repositories. Since I am ( obviously ) still installing GitLab I can't say what are the exact features, but clearly there is a wiki and issue trackiong and git_data_dir does not cover those, AFAIK. I'm looking for something that moves as much as is possible.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I suspect that some configuration options (i.e. how to change the wiki folder) still cannot be configured. You might want to submit an enhancement request should this be the case.