# Transfer gitlab repo to another drive

Tags: git, repository, gitlab, rsync

### Why?

I am going to have a big (>150gb) repository, that will fulfill main drive, so `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data` is not going to be enough. I want to move existing repository (and wiki) from `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/mygroup/myproject` to `/mnt/big-repos/git-data/mygroup/myproject`

### Info

- GitLab Community Edition 11.3.6

`/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
git_data_dirs({
   "alternative" => {
     "path" => "/mnt/big-repos/git-data"
    },
   "default" => {
     "path" => "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data"
    }
 })
```

### What I've tried?

1.

```
sudo -u git mkdir /mnt/big-repos/git-data/mygroup

sudo -u git mv /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/mygroup/myproject.*  /mnt/big-repos/git-data/mygroup

rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/mygroup/myproject.*

gitlab-ctl reconfigure
gitlab-ctl restart
```

Not working, cuz it keeps spawning everything in old direcory.

2.

```
sudo -u git mkdir /mnt/big-repos/git-data/mygroup

sudo rsync -av /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/mygroup/myproject.*  /mnt/big-repos/git-data/mygroup

rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/mygroup/myproject.*

gitlab-ctl reconfigure
gitlab-ctl restart
```

Same here. help

Comment: Related: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/moving_repositories.html

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902417/change-the-data-directory-gitlab-to-store-repos-elsewhere

Comment: Related Issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/55598